# What is this sample app trying to 'match'?

Tags: opencv

I'm looking at the LSDDetector implementation and found the sample app [matching.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/line_descriptor/samples/matching.cpp). Does anyone know what it's trying to 'match'? It seems to use two masks (`mask1` and `mask2`) of all ones and detect lines using them. What's the point of using masks of all ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are using a mask to specify a region-of-interest(ROI), so the processing is restricted to the region specified by the mask. Here's a simple example:

**image**

[image]

**mask**

[image: mask]

The given code is using the [BinaryDescriptor::operator()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/binary_descriptor.html#binarydescriptor-operator), to detect keylines and compute their descriptors in one call. It performs a detection on the whole image.

The code could also have used [BinaryDescriptor::detect](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/binary_descriptor.html#binarydescriptor-detect) followed by [BinaryDescriptor::compute](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/binary_descriptor.html#binarydescriptor-compute) for the same purpose.

[LSD](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/LSDDetector.html#line-segments-detector) is a line segment **detector** that uses the EDLN method given in the [references](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/LSDDetector.html#references) for line segment detection.

[BinaryDescriptor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/line_descriptor.html#binary-descriptors-for-lines-extracted-from-an-image) is a detector and a descriptor. It uses the LSD for line segment detection and uses the LBD method given in the [references](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/line_descriptor.html#references) for line description.

Comment: But how does the mask specify a ROI? For instance, `mask1` is of the same size as `imageMat1`. How does `lsd->detect( imageMat1, klsd1, 2, 2, mask1 );` impose a restricted area?

How is BinaryDescriptor different to LSDDetector?

Comment: Thanks. Unless I misunderstood the code, `mask1` (and `mask2`) are essentially all ones, i.e. wholly white. Effectively it's a redundant mask, isn't it?

Comment: @JohnMunroe When the mask is all ones, the whole image is processed. For example, if the mask given in the answer is used, only the regions covered by the white ellipses are processed in the given image.